# How to pass a struct member in one of the struct's method as default parameter?

Tags: c++, structure

I want to pass the variable `a` as a default parameter in method `func()`.

```
struct S {
    int a;
    int func(int b = a) {
        // do something
    }
};
```

On compiling it shows error. Is it possible to somehow get around this?

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible to use the value of a non-static member as default argument. You can use an overload instead:

```
struct S {
    int a;
    int func(int b) {
        // do something
    }
    int func() { return func(a); }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional):

```
struct S {
    int a;
    int func(std::optional<int> ob = std::nullopt) {
        int b = ob.value_or(a);
        // do something
    }
};
```